# C++ way to assign an array of char to a T* in a const method of a class

Tags: c++, casting

I would like to use some memory on the stack to store some objects (it arises in a small vector optimization library). Therefore, my class is

```
template <typename T, int n>
class SmallVector {
private:
    T* begin_;
    T* end_;
    T* capacity_;
    alignas(T) char data_small_[n * sizeof(T)];
public:
    ...
}
```

To check if the small_data_ buffer is used, I define the function

```
bool is_data_small_used() const {
    return begin_ == reinterpret_cast<T*>(data_small_);
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Clang version

```
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

gives me the following error message:

```
./il/container/SmallVector.h:44:25: error: reinterpret_cast from 'const char *' to 'il::Vector<double> *' casts away qualifiers
        return begin_ == reinterpret_cast<T*>(data_small_);
```

and the Intel compiler says the same. The only solution I found is to do

```
begin_ == (T*) data_small_
```

which is not very C++. Is there a "correct way" to do this in C++?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: What does *it does not work* mean? The `reinterpret_cast` [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55ef2315d4bb0359)

Comment: why are you even using `char`? Why not `T data_small_[n]`? (better yet, `std::array<T, n> data_small_`?)

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea. After assignment `begin_` wouldn't point to a T object, it would point to a raw memory area which if you lucky would be T object. There are many other options: use _placement new_, override new for some types...

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant that would require calling `n` constructors of `T()` on SmallVector creation which is not always good.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant see an implementation of `std::vector` for explanation; you don't want `vec.reserve(20);` to actually default-construct 20 objects

Comment: @SergeyKlyaus that's no problem, it's UB to dereference `begin` if the vector is empty so it doesnt matter if it points to uninitialized memory. Presumably OP will use placement new when it is time to add objects to the vector.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Sergey and Matt explained exactly the reason why I don't want to use an array of T.

Comment: @Sergey: The first thing I would do after this assignment is using placement new on begin_ if my SmallVector is not empty.

Comment: @InsideLoop the error message suggests you are writing that code inside a `const` member function  .. if so, make the function be non-const since it is modifying the state

Comment: @Matt: Good catch. I have updated the question so it is more clear. But my function is:    bool is_data_small_used() const { return data_ == reinterpret_cast<T*>(data_small_); } which does not modify anything. So it is const, isn't it?

Comment: @Matt: You are right. It's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message suggests that the problem is occurring inside a `const` member function. In that situation, `this` is considered to point to a const object, so `data_small_` will have type `const char[N]`.

A simple fix would be to write:

```
return begin_ == reinterpret_cast<T const *>(data_small_);
```

and another one would be:

```
return reinterpret_cast<char const *>(begin_) == data_small_;
```

The C-style cast worked because that cast can do a `reinterpret_cast` and a `const_cast` together, whereas a `reinterpret_cast` by itself cannot cast away `const`.